# Bit wise operator manipulation

Tags: python, arrays, operators

I have a column within a dataframe that consists of either `1`, `0` or `-1`.
For example:

`<0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,-1,0,0,1,0,0,-1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,-1,0,0>`

How can I create a new column in that dataframe where it is a sequence of 1s from the first `1` to the first `-1`. And then starts again at `0` until the next `1`.

In this example, it would be:

`<0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1, 1,0,0>`

Essentially I’m trying to create a trading strategy where I buy when the price is `>1.25` and sell when goes below `0.5`. `1` represents buy and `-1` represents sell. If I can get it into the form above I can easily implement it.

Comment: Why do you think the solution will involve bitwise operators?

Comment: I guess it’s the only thing I can think of

Comment: What exactly is the input object? Can you provide reproducible python code to initialize it?

Comment: Fairly new to coding so not really sure how to do that... Its a column within a dataframe where if the z-score goes above 1.25 I signal it +1 and if the z-score goes below 0.5 I signal it -1.

Comment: Please provide the DataFrame constructor (see my answer for an example, although I used a Series in my case, you can use `df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [values...]})`)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your data is stored but an algorithm similar to the following might work without the use of bitwise operators

```py
x = [0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,-1,0,0,1,0,0,-1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,-1,0,0]
newcol = []
flag = 0
for char in x:
    if char == 1 and flag == 0:
        flag = 1

    newcol.append(flag)

    if char == -1 and flag == 1:
        flag = 0

print(newcol)
```

Comment: Does this work if x is a column in a dataframe?

Comment: I get the error "length of values (1) does not match length of index (737739)

Comment: @Taffy if you have a DataFrame, then check my answer. And please update the question to reflect that this is a DataFrame (provide the constructor).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a good use case for [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas):

```
import pandas as pd


s = pd.Series([0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,-1,0,0,1,0,0,-1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,-1,0,0])
s2 = s.groupby(s[::-1].eq(-1).cumsum()).cummax()

print(s2.to_list())
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Sorry for all the silly questions and errors. New to stack overflow. :)